# wicket-jquery-ui Menu questions

Tags: jquery-ui, menu, wicket, integration

I have been looking to integrate jquery-ui into my wicket project and at first this seemed like the solution:

http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/

After building up the menu with dummy menu items all looks good except I have been unable to figure out how to set the response page on click.

I would be very appreciative if someone could direct me to an article or documentation on how to actually use the menu to set the response page.

Code so far looks exactly like that within the examples. Please post if you need any additional information

EDIT

http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/menu/DefaultMenuPage?19

So here is the code I was talking about but I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to actually use the menu to navigate to different pages within my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So here is the code I was talking about but I cannot seem to find any
>   documentation on how to actually use the menu to navigate to different
>   pages within my site.

It should work when you just call setResponsePage() within the onClick() method of your menu entry:

```
@Override
public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target){
  setResponsePage(TargetPage.class);
}
```

Comment: You would thing this to be the case but alas it is not.

Comment: Ahh I was being incredibly dense, the example code i ripped from the tutorial had the methods generating the menu lists as static and this prevented a call to setResponsePage()